# JS: Caching data in variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I am working on an angular (1.6) application that gets a lot of data from api. And to make the loading of the app faster we cache the data we get from the server to a variable so that we don't need to request the same data from the server.

My question is, is it bad practice to store data in a js variables? Will it have impact in the performance of the app?

Comment: _is it bad practice_ -- no, it isn't. It rather depends on the business use-case to decide what to cache. _Will it have impact in the performance_ -- depends on the type of data you're storing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing large amounts of data in variables can impact [memory usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) since storing a HTTP response would tell javascript to allocate memory for both the object/array as well as the object/array values.

AngularJS does support [caching](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching), but not by default, you need configure it:

```
$http.get(url, {cache: true}).success(...);
```

Using the above, Angular will make the request once and then fetch it from the cache next time the same request is made.

So you shouldn't need to store your HTTP response data in variables, instead let Angular handle the caching internally.

Comment: Is there a way in angular to cache responses from POST requests? Setting the cache to true was very helpful but only seems to work for GET requests.

Comment: Since post requests should be used to _send_ data, they cannot be cached, because if you try to send data to your server and the request is cached, the payload will never reach your server... Hope that makes sense. I guess you could cache the response from a post request, but then you might get a different response from your server than from you cache and could lead to unexpected behavior in your app.